# Posts and comments controls in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database, listview

I want to make a webpage using asp.net in which users can see others' posts and comment on them (like Facebook or Twitter). I couldn't find a proper control to view the posts from database and allow commenting on them and liking them. I searched the web, but there was no enough information about this topic.

I think I should use `ListView`, `DataList`, or `GridView`. However, customizing such controls is a bit limited, I couldn't figure out how to add the comment and like features in these controls.

How can I add the comment and like features to these controls? Or, is there a better control which I can use for this purpose?

I tried to use ListView, but I couldn't add comment area to it, here is my code:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [title] FROM [products]">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <span style="background-color: #FAFAD2; color: #284775;">title:
                        <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </span>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <span style="background-color: #FFCC66; color: #000080;">title:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </span>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <span>No data was returned.</span>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <span style="">title:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="titleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("title") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </span>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span style="background-color: #FFFBD6; color: #333333;">title:
                        <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                            <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align: center; background-color: #FFCC66; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333333;">
                        </div>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemTemplate>
                        <span style="background-color: #FFCC66; font-weight: bold; color: #000080;">title:
                        <asp:Label ID="titleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        </span>
                    </SelectedItemTemplate>

                </asp:ListView>

        </asp:Panel>
```

**EDIT: This is another method I tried with repeater:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [products]">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptEmployees" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div id="divEmployees">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="detail">
                   <div>Name: <strong> <%# Eval("title") %></strong></div>
                   <div>Address: <strong><%# Eval("price") %></strong></div>

                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <div class="detail">
                   <div>Name: <strong><%# Eval("title") %></strong></div>
                   <div>Address: <strong><%# Eval("price") %></strong></div>
                </div>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </div>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        </asp:Panel>
```

I found a website that explains how to use repeater to add comments to some posts, which is available here, http://dotprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-make-comment-box-in-aspnet.html

But, I think this illustrates how to add multiple comments to a single post. 
I want to have multiple posts, each can have multiple comments, how can I achieve that?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: use repeater and post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found that it can be possible by using nested `Repeaters`, one will represent the post itself, and the nested one is to represent the comments of the post.

For using `Repeaters` with comments this article was very helpful,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/